# pandas import error: cannot import name 'ndarray' from partially initialized module 'numpy'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm getting this error out of nowhere. Has anyone encountered this before?

pandas version = 1.4.2
numpy version = 1.22.3

raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: cannot import name 'ndarray' from partially initialized module 'numpy'

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Sounds like you have a circular import in your code somewhere.

Comment: I get the same error just by importing pandas

Comment: The classical way to get this type of error is to think "I'm going to play around with numpy, so I'll call my file `numpy.py`!". Then when you try to `import numpy`, your file will import itself and all sorts of confusion follow. If this is not the case, you will have to show us some code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: thank you, everyone! I figured out the reason. I had a file called signal.py. I never thought this would be the name of one of the implementations of pandas/numpy

Answer (score -1):

I was randomly getting this error on my MacOS with python3.

When I ran `import numpy` it was throwing the circular reference error.

To fix it I opened my terminal window and ran:

```bash
pip3 install --force --upgrade numpy
```

Hope this helps!